# MongoDB\Client not retrieving when using _id

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.6

I Am trying to reference some data from my mongodb Database within laravel

This is taken from the composer file for reference: `"mongodb/mongodb": "^1.3",`

**The following works fine:**

```
$collection->findOne( array( 'user_id' => (int)Auth::user()->id ) );
```

but i need to reference the data by the `_id` column

**When i do the following:**

```
$id = "5bb390bf421aa9bf4a1a85b7";
$details = $collection->findOne( array('_id' => $id) );
dd($details);
```

it just returns null

**Here is the mongodb table:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb390bf421aa9bf4a1a85b7"), 
    "auction_id" : NumberInt(36), 
    "user_id" : NumberInt(3), 
    "currency" : "0", 
    "status" : "3"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb390bf421aa9bf4b7540a7"), 
    "auction_id" : NumberInt(35), 
    "user_id" : NumberInt(3), 
    "currency" : "1", 
    "status" : "2"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb390bf421aa9bf4a1a85b8"), 
    "auction_id" : NumberInt(36), 
    "user_id" : NumberInt(3),
    "currency" : "0", 
    "status" : "1"
}
```

Added:

**if i try:**

```
$id = "5bb390bf421aa9bf4a1a85b7";
$details = $collection->findOne( array('_id' => ObjectId($id) ) );
dd($details);
```

**I receive this error:**

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\ObjectId()
```

**Also tried:**

```
$details = $collection->findOne( array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("5bb390bf421aa9bf4a1a85b8") ) );
```

**with the following error:**

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId' not found
```

Comment: _id is an ObjectId, you pass a string as param

Comment: how do i pass an object id?

Comment: something like new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("5bb390bf421aa9bf4a1a85b8")

Comment: Also, tried that, i'll update with the error

Comment: [Here's the doc](http://php.net/class.mongodb-bson-objectid) I don't know why your app is searching  this class in App\Http\Controllers, it must be an element of php / mongodb library. You perhaps need to import it before (never use Laravel)

Comment: me either, the read me isn't that helpful either

Comment: did you try something like `use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;` at start of your controller?

Comment: just tried `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId' not found`

Comment: this is the resource i have been working from for queries (https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/MongoDB%255CCollection/update/php-mongodb%255ccollection-update-method-examples.html),
but their examples do not work when using '_id', plus i can't for the life of me remember where i got the library from, it is just called mongodb/mongodb - as noted above

Comment: Have you tried `new ObjectID("5bb390bf421aa9bf4a1a85b7")`?